# CARBON TIME FORMATS

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

i am using Laravel 5.8 and in database there is a column name last_seen here stored values are in that format **(2021-02-05 00:42:14)** i want to customise this format on listing of a page just like  this **(22/04/2021 03:59:54)**
how can i do that ??

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO!  I can see your question has been answered, but your question has been proposed for closing.  There's a great guide on asking SO questions here, which I commend for all new users: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Carbon DateTime](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
Carbon::parse($user->last_visit)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: tahnx its working for me

Comment: @FarhanSakhawat Mark it as an accepted answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Include `last_seen` in the `dates` array in your model. Then you can use Carbon to format it however you like.

```
//in your model
protected $dates = ['last_seen'];

//controller or view
$model->last_seen->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

To address empty/null values in last_seen

```
optional($model->last_seen)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: i tried this solution got an error Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function format() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\icyber_shield\app\Repository\admin\UsersRepository.php:179

Comment: 'id' => $user->id,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'tickets' => '<a href= "' . $ticket_url . '">' . count($user->TicketAgents) . '<a>',
                'role' => !empty($user->role['name']) ? $user->role['name'] : 'Not Assigned',
                'lock_key' => isset($lock->key) ? $lock->key : '',
                'Last Login' => $user->last_visit->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'),
                'Login Status'   => getOnlineStatusById($user->id),
                'Google 2FA' => $faSecurity,

Comment: @FarhanSakhawat Called `format` on `null` means that there's no value in `last_seen`. You can avoid this by using the `optional` helper. `optional($model->last_seen)->format(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for changing the format of DateTime:

```
$datetime = "2021-02-05 00:42:14";
$datetime_format = Carbon::parse($datetime)->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'));
```

Output:

```
"2021/02/05 12:42:14"
```

Explanation of the formating:

1. H - 24 Hour with trailing zeros
2. i - Minutes with trailing zeros
3. s - Seconds with trailing zeros

For more details about the formatting of date-time please follow the link below:

[PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)